# Script to alter highlighted text in OS X - Script editor & Automator?

Tags: macos, automator

I frequently use Anki as a language-learning tool. I often find myself pasting text into Anki, which has superscripted characters. When I paste into Anki, it drops the superscripted characters and pastes as plain text.

[Here's an example of what I might paste into Anki.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQmNi.jpg)
When I paste into Anki, I'm left with "phohtH jaL naaM nooH grohmM thaiM", losing the superscripts. I have to manually change each one of these. I've done this thousands of times and would like to make this process more efficient.

I'd like to write some sort of script (ideally available through a right-click 'service' in OS X) that will alter highlighted text, searching the text for certain characters (namely "H", "M", "L", "F", "R" - always uppercase) and replacing those characters with identical *superscripted* characters, which in Anki can be accomplished with `<sup></sup>` tags (or manually typed by 'Command+Shift+*desired superscripted character*')

What's the best approach to make this happen? [I think I need something similar to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495102/editing-text-in-automator)

Note: I expect someone will suggested I turn off "strip HTML when posting text" in Anki. The problem with this is the source I copy from is located in cells and is often different sizes or linked text, so I get all sorts of stuff I don't want when I this option Anki doesn't strip HTML.

EDIT:

Solved. Found this Applescript solution:

```
sed 's/[HMLFR]/<sup>&<\/sup>/g' | pbcopy
```

Comment: Are you wanting the letters converted with `<sup></sup>` tags around them or into superscript?

Comment: I think directly converted to superscripts might be better. That'd save me a step in the process, assuming it works.